# Cannot edit WordPress plugin or theme files

Tags: wordpress

I cannot edit WordPress plugins or theme files. I get an error: "Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP."

Comment: How are you trying to edit the files? Also, do not edit plugin or theme files (unless its your plugin or your child theme) directly. Any changes you make will be lost. It appears you are on a managed hosting environment that runs code sniffing and error checking, so you should do as the message says - "use SFTP"

Comment: Hi disinfor, through the editor. It is only for theme or plugin files; new pages and posts works. Works on HTTP only and previous versions of WordPress.

Comment: So you do not have any FTP access? I would recommend using this instead of the build in editor of wordpress. Check your webhost account to get the FTP login data. The error says he cannot make sure that your changes do not cause fatal errors, so it won't let you save the file via this editor.

Comment: I do have FTP access. Okay, will just either downgrade WordPress or use FTP solution instead.